# Resolution problem on Intel 950 GPU with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, resolution

I just got a nice looking ultra mini desktop for US$ 150, which uses a Digisol Motherboard with a Atom Dual Core 1.8 Ghz Processor - D425, with 2 GB RAM. I have a Dell 22" monitor connected to the machine. The maximum resolution does not go beyond 1024 x 800. I tried updating the system, but some how it is not going beyond 1024 x800.

The built in graphics card is Intel GPU 950. The chipset is Intel NM10. There are no resolution issues with Ubuntu 10.04 on the same machine. It gives a 1920 x 1200 and works quite fast and is stable.

Any suggestions on how to handle this? Where can I download the drivers from?

Answer (score 1):

Install the intel graphics drivers using:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I also have an Intel notebook graphics card and I am wondering that yours works with 10.04 - mine does not. With 11.04 mine does work, 11.10 I have not installed.

Comment: What chipset and what GPU do you have on the notebook?. Mine worked out of the box on the above machine.